# Is it possible to retrieve IPv6 address using QAbstractSocket?

Tags: qt, ipv6

Is it possible to retrieve the IPv6 address on a `QAbstractSocket`? You can retrieve the IPv4 one using `QAbstractSocket::peerAddress()` but I'm not sure about the IPv6 one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the documentation. The `peerAddress()` returns a generic `QHostAddress` -- it's not limited to IPv4! As long as you've connected to an IPV6 peer, the full IPV6 address will be returned by using `QHostAddress::toIPv6Address`. Like this:

```
QAbstractSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress("2607:f8b0:4009:803::1005"), 80); // google.com
....
const QHostAddress & addr = socket.peerAddress();
if (addr.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol) {
  Q_IPV6ADDR address6 = addr.toIPv6Address();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But a question, let's say i'm connecting to my server using IPv4, it's still possible to get the IPv6? (Sorry, maybe i mis-understood your answer).

Comment: @Blastcore: It *might* be possible. If you are connecting to a host via IPV4 by its DNS name, then you might simply look for IPV6 addresses in its DNS record. If you know only IPV4 address, then you can learn the DNS name via reverse DNS lookup.